# What plants won't do well in 12 inch raised bed

Tags: vegetables, containers, roots, raised-beds, fruits

I built a 12 inch raised garden bed with weed tarp at the bottom. (See also [Raised garden in flood zone](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/56654/raised-garden-in-flood-zone.)) I put the weed tarp in to prevent grass and other weeds from coming up from the ground. This has the negative effect of preventing roots from the plants I plant from going deeper than about 11 inches. Here is a photo:

[image]

What types of fruits, vegetables, and sunflowers will not do well in this setting due to their roots needing to go deeper?

Comment: The other negative effect is that the fabric will also block movement of beneficial organisms (earthworms). I dug up my fixed beds and removed the fabric I originally installed... I will deal with the grass/weeds.